# Que pasa con los mensajes consumidos en apache KAFKA?

Tags: mensajes

Apache Kafka es un sistema de manejo de colas de mensajes por suscripción, los mensajes son enviados al cluster por los productores y luego estos son leídos por los consumidores. pero que pasa con el mensaje cuando es consumido? queda almacenado? queda guardado en el cluster o es borrado y eliminado?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje en Kafka se mantiene almacenado en los servidores dependiendo de la configuración.  Hay configuración de preservación de los logs por tópico, los cuales contienen todos los mensajes.

Hay dos maneras de configurar esto:  Por tiempo, y por tamaño en bytes de los logs.  La recomendación general es configurar la retención por tiempo solamente (el default en las ultimas versiones de 7 días), ya que configurar por bytes puede llevar, en situaciones de alto volumen, a la pérdida de datos.

La configuración a nivel general en los servidores es `log.retention.ms`, y la configuración por tópico se controla con `retention.ms`.  Para más información, puedes leer todas las opciones aquí:

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#configuration